# Sampling with replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How-many distinct samples of size $n$ can be drawn with replacement from the population ${u_1, u_2,......, u_n}$ of $n$ units ?

I have considered the number of ways in which $n$ units can occupy $n$ places.

Comment: Do you care about the order in which the units are sampled? Do you care about the number of times each unit is sampled? Or do you care only about which units are sampled? In other words, how are you defining *distinct*?

Answer (score 1):

I preassume that the order in which the units are chosen *does not* play a part in distinghuishing the samples, and secondly that number of times a unit is sampled *does* play a part in this.

Let $k_i$ denote the number of times that unit $u_i$ appears in the sample.

Then $k_1+\cdots+k_n=n$ where the $k_i$ are nonnegative integers.

With [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) we find that there are: $$\binom{n+(n-1)}{n-1}=\binom{2n-1}{n-1}=\binom{2n-1}{n}$$ possibilities.